# How to create multiple user account for git and gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, multiple-accounts

I am trying to set up a new project in Git,four people are going to work on the project.

May i know the process to create multiple accounts for git and gerrit so that four  developers will have their own user account ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. The Gerrit Administrator or someone who has been assigned the 
   Global Capability - Create Account creates four Gerrit accounts.
2. The Gerrit Administrator or someone who has been assigned the Global Capability - Create Project creates a repository for your project.
3. The Gerrit Administrator or someone who has been assigned the Global Capability - Create Group creates one or more groups for access control. Add the members to these groups according to their roles. Assign different access rights to these groups.
4. Every member generates a pair of ssh keys in their working machine. Copy the content of the public key and paste it to the ssh-key filed in their Gerrit profile.
5. Run `git config --global user.name <name>` and `git config --global user.email <email>` to setup the name and email used in Git commits. And make other config if necessary.
6. Clone the repository from Gerrit.

Answer (score -1):

please see below links for detailed information

[Adding outside collaborators to repositories in your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/)

or

[Inviting collaborators to a personal repository](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/)

Comment: As far as I see OP is not talking about GitHub.